# Using powershell to add a hyperlink to an excel worksheet that has parenthesis in its name

Tags: excel, powershell

Consider the following powershell code, which creates a new excel workbook, adds two new worksheets "ABCD" and "A(BC)D", and creates hyperlinks to these sheets within Sheet1.

```
# Create the excel com object
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$ws1 = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)

# Add a new worksheet named "ABCD"
$ws2 = $wb.Worksheets.Add()
$ws2.Name = "ABCD"

# Add a new worksheet named "A(BC)D"
$ws3 = $wb.Worksheets.Add()
$ws3.Name = "A(BC)D"

# Add a hyperlink to worksheet "ABCD" in worksheet "Sheet1"
$ws1.Hyperlinks.Add($ws1.Cells.Item(1,1),"", "ABCD!A1") | Out-Null

# Add a hyperlink to worksheet "A(BC)D" in worksheet "Sheet1"
$ws1.Hyperlinks.Add($ws1.Cells.Item(2,1),"", "A(BC)D!A1") | Out-Null
```

The second hyperlink fails to reference worksheet "A(BC)D", probably because there are parenthesis in the sheet name.

I've tried escaping the parenthesis using '`' and '\', but that does not seem to work.

Is there a way to create a hyperlink to an excel worksheet that has parenthesis in the name using powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it worked like this:

```
$ws1.Hyperlinks.Add($ws1.Cells.Item(2,1),"", "`'A(BC)D`'!A1") | Out-Null
```