# How to create hyperlinked index of sheets in workbook?

Tags: powershell

I am having a excel workbook with 1000 worksheets in it.

I want to create a index page with link to all these worksheets. so if we click in one like it should navigate to that specific worksheet. Like below

[image]

Need some idea on how to do this

I don't have excel installed in the server from where i am executing the below code to generate the excel file.

```
$path = "C:\Scripts\"
$csvs = Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.csv
$excelFileName = Join-Path $path -ChildPath "$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd)_combineddata.xlsx"

foreach ($csv in $csvs)
{
    $content = Import-Csv -Path $csv

    $props = @{
        WorksheetName = $csv.BaseName
        PassThru = $true
        InputObject = $content
    }

    if(-not $xlsx)
    {
        $props.Path = $excelFileName
        $xlsx = Export-Excel @props

        continue
    }

    $props.ExcelPackage = $xlsx
    Export-Excel @props > $null
}

Close-ExcelPackage $xlsx
```

**Update**

I managed to create the final excel with Index sheet at first with all the other sheet names.

I am using **ImportExcel Module** as i don't have excel installed in server

How to convert those into hyperlinks

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132526/using-powershell-to-add-a-hyperlink-to-an-excel-worksheet-that-has-parenthesis-i)

Comment: I missed to mention, but the server from where i am executing the script there is no excel installed.